# How to pass the Amplify app ID to a function? How to do app introspection from backend functions?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-amplify

### Background

Amplify apps are easily extensible with Lambda functions, using `amplify add function`.  Great!

### Problem

How can I access the Amplify app ID from the Lambda function code?  There are a lot of scenarios where I need that string in order to locate resources or access secrets in SSM.

### More generally

How can my function do introspection on the app?  How can I get the app ID from the Lambda function?  Is there a service?  Am I supposed to pass the information (somehow) through the CloudFormation template for the function?

### Due diligence

I've spent days trying to figure this out, and I have at least learned the secret, undocumented way to get anything in a nested CloudFormation stack's outputs into the parameters for my CloudFormation stack, so that I can create environment variables that my Lambda function can see.

That does not solve my original problem of finding the top-level app ID.  Or any information about the top-level app.  If I could find the stack name for the top-level CloudFormation for the stack then I could learn a lot of things.  I can't.

##### How to pass stack outputs from app resources into function stack parameters

I've spent days trying to figure this out, and I have at least learned the secret, undocumented way to use `dependsOn` in the backend-config.json to get the outputs from the CloudFormation stacks for other resources in the Amplify app and feed those into the parameters for my stack for my function:

```
 "function": {
    "MyFunctionName": {
      "build": true,
      "providerPlugin": "awscloudformation",
      "service": "Lambda",
      "dependsOn": [
        {
          "category": "api",
          "resourceName": "Data",
          "attributes": [
            "GraphQLAPIIdOutput"
          ]
        }
      ],
    }
  }
}
```

That creates a new parameter for your function that's named using a pattern that's not documented anywhere, from what I can tell: `[category][resource name][CloudFormation stack output name]`.  You can reference that in your CloudFormation stack for your function to create an environment variable that your function code can access:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Parameters": {
    ...
    "secretsPathAmplifyAppId": {
      "Type": "String"
    }
    ...
  "Resources": {
    ...
        "Environment": {
          "Variables": {
            "AMPLIFY_APP_ID": {
              "Ref": "secretsPathAmplifyAppId"
            },
```

##### Using the `AmplifyAppId` in `amplify-meta.json` doesn't work

If I could access the `provider` / `cloudformation` data from a `dependsOn` then I could get the app ID into my function's stack.  But that doesn't work.  I spent some time eliminating that possibility.

##### Using `secretsPathAmplifyAppId`

There is a side effect of using amplify update function to add secrets.  If you add any secret to the function then you will get a new parameter as an input to your function's CloudFormation stack: `secretsPathAmplifyAppId`

I did that and added a dummy secret that I don't really need, in order to get that CloudFormation stack parameter containing the Amplify App ID that I do need.  And then I referenced that in my CloudFormation template for my function:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Parameters": {
    ...
    "env": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "s3Key": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    ...
    "secretsPathAmplifyAppId": {
      "Type": "String"
    }
```

That works, right?  **No!**

If I create a new app in Amplify, perhaps deploying it to a staging or production account for the first time, then I'll get the error `Parameters: [secretsPathAmplifyAppId] must have values` from the initial build when I press "Save and Deploy" on the "Host your web app" form.  This is because using `secretsPathAmplifyAppId` relies on the Amplify CLI adding the value to the `team-provider-info.json` file.  For a new app's first deployment, "the `team-provider-info.json` file is not available in the Admin UI deployment job", as described in https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/8513 .  And there is apparently no solution.

### WHY IS THIS SO HARD?!?

The Amplify documentation implies that it's not difficult to add a Lambda function and do whatever.  I'm a Lambda master and a code master, and I can do whatever.  But only if I can pass context information to my code.

How can an Amplify app's Lambda functions do introspection on the app?

Answer (score 1):

Amplify provisions resources using Cloudformation, a root stack is spun for a project while resources in each category are spun using `Nested` stacks. `Cloudformation` stacks are stateless and so are the underlying resources. Cloudformation stack won't have any idea how it was generated, nor would the underlying resource know if it was provisioned through `Cloudformation`.

When you do `amplify add function`, you can name your function with `Amplify app id` as a workaround and then access the function's name from the `context` object as following:

`context.functionName` for [NodeJS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-context.html)

`context.function_name` for [Python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context.html)

Alternatively, you can add a tag for your `app-id` in `tags.json` under `backend` folder as following and run `amplify push --yes` which will update the tags on your function and then you can call [list-tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/list-tags.html) api to fetch the tags where you will find the App ID.

```
{
        "Key": "App-Id",
        "Value": "aasdasdasdasads"
}
```

Or you can modify your [function](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/function/env-vars/) to add the app id as `environment variable` and retrieve it in the [code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-retrieve).

Comment: Thank, you.  Problem, though: Adding the app ID to the function name and then using that ID would tie my code base to that specific deployment.  My goal here it to create code that I can deploy to multiple Amplify "apps" in multiple AWS accounts.  We need to keep our application code general.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it.  AWS, please make this easier.  IMHO, the app ID should be available to a function by default.  If not, then it should be simpler than what I had to go through.  It should at least be documented.  And the documentation about what environment variables exist appears to be incorrect.  Or else maybe I misunderstood it and that still seems like a problem.

## Variable handoff from build time to runtime

The overall technique is to pass the `AWS_APP_ID` environment variable from the build-time environment to the Lamda runtime environment where it will be available to the Lambda function.

### AWS_APP_ID is available at build time

[This page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html#amplify-console-environment-variables) in the Amplify documentation lists a set of environment variables that are supposed to be available at build time.  It's not true.  The only variable in the list that's available at build time is `AWS_APP_ID`.  That's enough, though.

### Interpolate AWS_APP_ID into CloudFormation template

I cited the variable in my CloudFormation template for my function like this:

```
        "Environment": {
          "Variables": {
            "AWS_APP_ID": "{{AWS_APP_ID}}",
```

Then I set up my build to use an off-the-shelf NPM to interpolate the variable into that.  The `{{}}` syntax comes from that NPM.  There is probably a way to do this with `sed` or something that could make the build process faster and not dependent on that NPM.

### Access environment variable from Lambda function normally

Then you can access the app ID from the Lambda function in the normal way for the function's runtime:

```
const app_id = process.env.AWS_APP_ID
console.log(`app_id: ${app_id}`)
```